# Using a USB driver for PIC18F27J53

Tags: c, usb, mplab, pic18

I am attempting to use a PIC18F27J53 to decode the output from a Nintendo Entertainment System controller and use it as a USB compatible HID Joystick.

I have successfully been able to read the output 60 times per second and store the status of each button as one bit of an 8-bit unsigned char. I'm using the USB's 5V and Gnd for both the PIC and the NES controller, and I send the latch signal via RB1, the clock via RB2, and the data is read in via RB0.

http://www.mit.edu/~tarvizo/nes-controller.html

http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39964B.pdf

Here's where I need help: figuring out how to interface with the USB data lines. I've downloaded the Microchip USB C libraries but have no idea where to start with them. I'm programming in MPLAB X IDE using the C18 compiler.